# jquery selector syntax $( [] ) and $("*")

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

The following line of code comes from the official [dialog/#modal-form example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form)

```
allFields = $( [] ).add( name )
```

Could someone please clarify what `$( [] )` does? Is it the same as `$("*")`?

Another thing puzzled me is that I did not see `allFields` being added/appended to anywhere/any object, it is only created and modified. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at the [doco for the `jQuery()` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) - usually seen as the shorthand version `$()` - you'll see that it accepts several different types and combinations of parameters.

The syntax you asked about:

```
$([])
```

is the `jQuery( elementArray )` syntax which lets you pass an array of DOM elements where the return will be a jQuery object wrapping those elements. By passing an empty array you basically get an empty jQuery object (just as you would if you passed a selector string that didn't match anything, but without the inefficiency of trying to find a match first).

When created `allFields` has three DOM elements added to it (where `name`, `email` and `password` are created just before that as jQuery objects containing one DOM element each):

```
allFields = $( [] ).add( name ).add( email ).add( password )
```

Presumably the advantage of adding the individual items rather than just doing:

```
allFields = $("#name,#email,#password")
```

is that the individual objects for each element were also needed and would've been created anyway, so no need to bother reselecting them via a query string.

> Another thing puzzled me is that I did not see `allFields` being added/appended to anywhere/any object, it is only created and modified, am I missing something?

It is referred to in two other places in the code:

```
allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
// and, later
allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
```

This is fairly standard jQuery usage to remove a class or set the value of all elements in the jQuery object. No need for it to be added to some other object.

Answer (score 5):

`$([])` creates an empty jQuery object, just like `$()`. `$('*')` creates a jQuery object which holds all elements which match the CSS selector `*`, which every element will match.

In other words, `$([])` gets nothing, `$('*')` gets everything.

Answer (score 1):

> jQuery( elementArray )
>
> elementArray: An array containing a set of DOM elements to wrap in a
>   jQuery object.

`$( [] )` create en empty set that wrapped in a jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are referring to the following lines:

```
var name = $( "#name" ),
    email = $( "#email" ),
    password = $( "#password" ),
    allFields = $( [] ).add( name ).add( email ).add( password )
```

What is happening here is that they selected three elements and now they want to create a single jQuery object that references all three.

This is the same as the following except that they avoided the selector calls:

```
   allFields = $("#name, #email, #password")
```

In essence, they created a zero element jQuery object with `$([])` then appended, name, email, and password so the final object was a jQuery object of length 3.